# Individually color characters in QLabel

Tags: qt, qlabel

I am trying to find out if there is a way to split the text contained inside a QLabel into
multiple labels, one for each character in the text.

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to color each character in the label individually, so I can make them either red or green. I am trying to build a touch typing game where the user inputs data and it gets checked against a reference string he is looking at, which gets red or green depending on if he made a mistake or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Qt's rich text facilities to color your characters. It is a subset of HTML ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)).
Example:

```
label.setText("A<span style='color: red;'>B</span>C");
```

You can use [`QLabel::setTextFormat(Qt::TextFormat)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop) to enable or disable this functionality. The default is enabled-by-heuristic (`Qt::AutoText`).